# How to get knockout old value before binding set to new value?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i am doing custom binding to display the score :

my html like like this

```
<div class="notesite" id="note_1" data-bind="Score: ScoreValue()"></div>

self.ScoreValue= ko.observable("");
```

binding is like that :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.Score = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var myscorevalue = valueAccessor();
        if (myscorevalue) {

            //if(myscorevalue is decrease)
            {
                $("#divarrow").hide();
            }
            //if(myscorevalue is increasing)
            {
                $("#divarrow").show();
            }
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var myscorevalue = valueAccessor();
        if (myscorevalue) {

            //if(myscorevalue is decrease)
            {
                $("#divarrow").hide();
            }
            //if(myscorevalue is increasing)
            {
                $("#divarrow").show();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

my issue is , based on score i passed , i want to show up and down arrow !

lets see my value is = self.ScoreValue("10")

and then i updated value to self.ScoreValue("15")

then i want to show `$("#divarrow").show();`

if i updated value to self.ScoreValue("5")

then i want to hide `$("#divarrow").hide();`

Answer (score 2):

You can create another field (ex. `PreviousScoreValue`)  that will have the previous score using [`beforeChange`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) subscription:

```
self.PreviousScoreValue = ko.observable(self.ScoreValue());

self.ScoreValue.subscribe(function(value) {
    self.PreviousScoreValue(value);
}, null, 'beforeChange');
```

Then in the custom binding, use it to compare to new `ScoreValue`:

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel,
                bindingContext) {
    var myscorevalue = valueAccessor();
    var previousvalue = bindingContext.$data.PreviousScoreValue();

    if (myscorevalue) {
        if(myscorevalue < previousvalue)
        {
            $("#divarrow").hide();
        } else if(myscorevalue > previousvalue)
        {
            $("#divarrow").show();
        }
    }
},
```